# jQuery ajax post done/success/delete cookie after

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, cookies

I'm trying to achieve a simple jQuery ajax post containing a stringified(?) object.  I'm achieving this by gathering the information I intend to post on a registration page then using JSON.stringify and storing the object in a cookie.  Upon successful registration the object is posted in the data parameter of the ajax post on the following page.

So far so good.  Post success, API receives the object and interprets the data.  However, when the user navigates back to this page (containing their user info) and has the cookie set, the post request is sent again, and again, and again every time they hit the page.

I'd like to achieve something like this:

```
if(CMjar.getKeys().indexOf('registerSession') != -1) {  //if cookie exists
    $.ajax({
        url: 'API URL',
        type: 'POST',
        data: stringyObjS,
        dataType: 'json',
    }) // post the request 
        .done(function() {  //once posted
            CMjar.remove('registerSession');  //delete the cookie
        });

    console.log('posted');
};  // if cookie doesn't exist don't do anything
```

When working in the console, the CMjar.remove function works as expected and the cookie is gone, but it isn't being called by .done.  Any ideas?  Should I be using suceess:?

I have also tried the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'API URL',
    type: 'POST',
    data: stringyObjS,
    dataType: 'json',
}); // post the data
CMjar.remove('registerSession'); // delete the cookie
```

This works in the sense that it deletes the cookie, although I do receive a syntax error when it should be sending the post request (I haven't replicated this since so can't quote the error verbatim).

Am I on the right track?  Am I being stupid?  Please help!

Thanks,
Myles

Answer (score 0):

All sorted - I must have had a syntax error that was preventing the post request from working, just tried removing the cookie without the .done function and it's worked as it should.

For those interested, here is my solution:

** REGISTER PAGE **

```
$('.marg-bottom .button').click(function() {

                        var postMobEmailOpt;

                            if ($('#usxtsubscribesms').is(':checked')) {
                                postMobEmailOpt = 'I';
                            } else {
                                postMobEmailOpt = 'O';
                            };

                        var obj= {
                            type: 'mergeListMembers',
                            source: 'registrationForm',
                            EMAIL_FORMAT_: 'H',
                            TITLE: $('#title').val(),
                            FIRST_NAME: $('#fname').val(),
                            LAST_NAME: $('#lname').val(),
                            COUNTRY_: $('#cntrylist').val(),
                            POSTAL_CODE_: $('#zipc').val(),
                            HOUSE_NUM: $('#num').val(),
                            POSTAL_STREET_1_: $('#addr1').val(),
                            POSTAL_STREET_2_: $('#addr2').val(),
                            CITY_: $('#city').val(),
                            COUNTY: $('#statetext').val(),
                            MOBILE_NUMBER_: $("input[name='usxusxtmobile']").val(),
                            EMAIL_ADDRESS_: $('#usemail').val(),
                            GENDER: $('#usxusxtgender').val(),
                            DATE_OF_BIRTH: $('#usxusxtbirthdate').val() + '-' +     $('#usxusxtbirthmonth').val() + '-' + $('#usxusxtbirthyear').val(),
                            POSTAL_PERMISSION_STATUS_: postMobEmailOpt,
                            MOBILE_PERMISSION_STATUS_: postMobEmailOpt,
                            EMAIL_PERMISSION_STATUS_: postMobEmailOpt
                        }

                        var CMjar = new CookieJar( {expires: '', path: '/'} );

                            CMjar.put('registerSession', JSON.stringify(obj));

                    });

                })
```

** ACCOUNT PAGE (navigated to, after registration **

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {

    var CMjar = new CookieJar( {expires: '', path: '/'} ),
        stringyObj = CMjar.get('registerSession'),
        stringyObjS = $.parseJSON(stringyObj);

if(CMjar.getKeys().indexOf('registerSession') != -1) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'URL',
        type: 'POST',
        data: stringyObjS,
        dataType: 'json',
    });
            CMjar.remove('registerSession');

};

});
```